# Get Data from Array Without Quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I having a problem with an array inside a JavaScript, and I don't how I can get the data from inside the array. This is the code:

```
array = [A(-11.8,166.88),A(-11.8,166.88),A(-11.8,166.88)]


function A(a,b) {
    polyCoords.push(projTransform(a,b));
```

}

I want to get each lat and long separate in javascript format, but I don't know how I can proceed. Probably is more easier than I think, but currently I block with this.

Do you have any idea on how can I proceed?

The result that I want is to obtain this data.

```
array[0] = [-11.8,166.88]
array[1] = [-11.8,166.88]
array[2] = [-11.8,166.88]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly does `A()` return from it's method calls?

Comment: Taplar is right.  We can't really answer without knowing `A`.  Are you using some library?

Comment: @Taplar A is the call of a coordinate, makes the separation between differentd coordinates.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  You are making a function call to `A()` three times.  The three results of which, will comprise your array.  It's unclear from this fact what you are trying to do/get

Comment: If all you want is the data just grab it by index `array[0]`. Or do a for-loop through the array.

Comment: @Taplar I just edit the post with the A function.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get anything.  A() does not return a value.  array is going to equal `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @Taplar A, means taht inside there is a lat and long. The problem is inside the array, I can't separate de data (always return NaN/undefined) because there are not in a string "" (with quotes).

Comment: A does not mean that.  A is a method.  That's what A means.  The array is not going to exist with unexecuted functions in it.  It's going to execute those three functions and put the results of them in the array.  And as I just explained in my previous method, the results will be undefined because your A() method does not return a result.

Comment: However, it is still unclear what your desired end result is.  If you desire some sort of object with the parameters that are being passed into each of the function calls in the array, then that appears to be a fairly easy task, given that they are static values in your question.  If they are dynamic values, then it could still be done, however if that is the case then this question does not appropriately reflect your existing code and *should*

Comment: @Taplar True, I just edit agian the post. That is how I want the data.

Comment: `array[0] = -11.8,166.88` doesn't make sense.  You can't have two values as a single value of an element, unless it's in an array.  `array[0] = [-11.8,166.88]`

Comment: @Taplar yeah, full agre with you. Is possible to get the data like you said array[0] = [-11.8,166.88] ?

Comment: Your `projTransform(a, b)` should return an array. So then you can say `array = [projTransform(x, y), projTransform(x, y), projTransform(x, y)]` and from there you can do something like `array.forEach(coord => console.log(coord))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [A(-11.8,166.88),A(-11.8,166.88),A(-11.8,166.88)];

function A(a,b) {
  //polyCoords.push(projTransform(a,b));
  
  //you need to return a value, otherwise the result of the method
  //is undefined
  return [a, b];
}

console.log(array);
console.log(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
console.log(array[1][0], array[1][1]);
console.log(array[2][0], array[2][1]);
```

Comment: Just to flesh out your answer I would suggest how OP could gain access to each inner array as well. `array[0][0]` for example. Just my two cents.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield added

Comment: @Taplar  Thanks so much, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: But it really makes no sense.  Why wouldn't you just define the array without the crazy function call (and then forEach it into your polyCoords object).

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you want to define the array and then add it to polyCoords.

```
var array = [[-11.8,166.88],[-11.8,166.88],[-11.8,166.88]];

array.forEach(el => polyCoords.push(projTransform(el[0], el[1])));
```